# Samsung S3: Only retrieve "contact with number" in contact search

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Synchronizing my phone with my gmail account it has imported, not only the contacts, but even all the people who I just wrote one mail in my life (even without phone number).
I have hidden this contacts checking "show only contact with number" but if I perform a search  this contacts appear. How can I really delete it, and set my phone to only consider GMail contacts (https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, GMail won't put people you have only emailed into your "My Contacts" built-in group (See [Gmail and auto-adding contacts](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/07/gmail-to-no-longer-auto-add-contacts.html)).

Because of this, you should be able to tell android to only pull from your "My Contacts" list, which would presumably only contain  your important contacts.

The steps to do this will vary depending on your ROM. I'm using a nightly build of CM10, and these are the steps:

1. Open Contacts
2. Press Menu button, and choose "Contacts to display"
3. Choose "Customize"
4. Choose the account of interest, and make sure only "My Contacts" is
   checked/selected (Or any other groups you want).

Hopefully that helps you out, or at least gives you an idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: This will work, but just handle the contacts showed. When I perform a search, all mail contact appear, even facebook account etcetc

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm at a loss, then.